# The covariant derivative of a covariant vector

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

So I am confused: in the original setting with coordinates we have
$$\nabla_i T_j = \partial_i T_j - \Gamma^k_{ij} T_k$$
Does that mean, for $\vec X_j=\partial_j \vec R$, we have
$$\nabla_i \vec X_j = \partial_i \vec X_j - \Gamma^k_{ij} \vec X_k =  \Gamma^k_{ij} \vec X_k -  \Gamma^k_{ij} \vec X_k= 0$$

But in the conventional system we have
$$\nabla_{\frac {\partial} {\partial X^i}} \frac {\partial} {\partial X^j} = \Gamma_{ij} ^k \frac {\partial} {\partial X^k} $$
What did I miss?

Comment: Don't omit the basis vectors! Your first equation actually means $$\nabla_i(T)=\nabla_i(T_je^j)=(\partial_iT_j)e^j+T_j(\nabla_i e^j)$$ $$=(\partial_iT_j)e^j+T_j(-\Gamma^j_{ik}e^k)=(\partial_iT_j-T_k\Gamma^k_{ij})e^j$$ In fact I see no need for two different symbols $\partial,\nabla$ when this is clarified.

Comment: Your mistake is in applying that formula (your first line) to a _vector_ $\vec X_j$, while it's meant for _scalar components_ of a _covector_ $T$.